# zsh beeping in Intellij-Idea

Tags: terminal, zsh, intellij-idea

When I configure my Intellij (community edition - 2021.1) to use zsh, everytime I type in a command in the terminal there is a beep sound. I already set `unsetopt beep` in my .zshrc and also ticked off the option `Audible bell` in the intellij settings under `Tools/Terminal`.

When I use bash everything works fine without any sounds.

Does anyone have the same problem or a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219283

If you comment out lines 21-22 of `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/termsupport.zsh` it should get rid of the bell. Be aware that you will get merge issues that have to be resolved when they update that file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have not tried to use Intellij with zsh for a while and just switched again to test your fix. Apparently the problem was fixed and I did not even have to comment out the lines.